# Cloudbuild can't find my package.json from my Vue app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-app-engine, yarnpkg, google-cloud-build

I am attempting to deploy a Vue JS app to GCP App Engine via GCP Cloud Build. I've followed the instructions and have created a cloudbuild.yaml file in a separate directory from the app.yaml file. The build errors with

`error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/workspace"`

It looks like the first two steps of the cloudbuild.yaml file execute successfully, but it fails when it tries to run the build.

The directory is like so:

```
root/
├─ config/
│  ├─ cloudbuild.yaml
app.yaml
package.json
```

Here is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs10
service: icx-ui

handlers:
# Serve all static files with urls ending with a file extension
- url: /(.*\..+)$ 
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*\..+)$
# catch all handler to index.html
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

My cloudbuild.yaml is as follows:

```
steps:
  - name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ["install"]
  - name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ['global', 'add', '@vue/cli']
  - name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ["run", "build"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy", "./app.yaml"]
    timeout: "1600s"
```

As you can see, I add a file path to my app.yaml file

Comment: How do you run your Cloud Build? What is the command or the trigger configuration?

Comment: Sure thing. I am at the project root and sending the `--config` flag. Here is the command I use to trigger the build `gcloud builds submit --config ./config/cloudbuild.yaml ./dist`. The last parameter is the directory where the build files are

Comment: Thanks to your comment, Dondi has provided the correct answer ;)

Comment: Thank you @dondi. Project has been successfully built and deployed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defined source directory of your `gcloud builds submit` command is `dist/` which is the built, production version of your app. This directory does not contain both package.json and app.yaml by default.

Running `yarn run build` on Cloud Build requires files such as `src/` and `package.json` to build the
files (dist) that you will serve via App Engine. The solution is to specify the root project as the source directory of the build:

```
gcloud builds submit --config ./config/cloudbuild.yaml .
```

If at some case this brought you concerns where some unnecessary files are included on deployment such as `node_modules`, you can ignore such files by specifying them on `.gcloudignore`.